# Laravel 8 404 Not Found page returned for all routes on ubuntu 18 an apache

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu, laravel-8

My laravel 8 project is running in a local environment with Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4.29 and php 7.3.22. It is working, but in my prod server with the same versions I got 404 for all routes. I already enabled rewrite module `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and my virtual host is like bellow:

```
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/project/public

<Directory /home/ubuntu/project/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

also I changed storage forder owner `sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data storage`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using apache and your virtual host **config** is `ok` and you are using this `AllowOverride all` `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` in your `<Directory>`

Just run this command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And restart your apache by this command:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

It's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

your virtual host should have the contain below:

```
 <Directory /home/ubuntu/project/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

your vitual host should look like this in order to work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin admin@test.com
ServerAlias test.local
ServerName test.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/public

<Directory /var/www/html/test/public>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.local-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.local-access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Test is the name of the project which can be as you want.

You can access your project on test.local without php artisan serve

Edit: dont forget to add an entry to the machine hosts file as follow:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

add this line:

```
127.0.0.1       test.local
```

`ctrl+o` to save and `ctrl+x` to exit

Last step, just restart the apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

PS: If `127.0.0.1` is already taken you can set another ip like: `127.0.0.2`